# Conditional addition in Python

Tags: python

I have been struggling with a text file to perform conditional appending/extending certain text using Python. My apologies in advance if this is too basic and already been discussed here in someway or the other :(

Concerning the code (attached), I need to add statement "mtu 1546" under the statement containing "description" only if it doesn't exist. Also, I would like to be able add "description TEST" statement under interface statement (and/or above mtu statement, if available) only if doesn't pre-exist. I am using python 2.7.

Here's is my code:

```
import re

f = open('/TESTFOLDER/TEST.txt','r')
interfaces=re.findall(r'(^interface Vlan[\d+].*\n.+?\n!)',f.read(),re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

for i in interfaces:
    interfaceslist = i.split("!")
    for i in interfaceslist:
        if "mtu" not in i:
            print i


f.close()
```

print statement works fine with the condition as it's able to print the interesting lines correctly, however my requirement is to add (append/extend) the required statements to the list so I can further use it for parsing and stuff. Upon, trying append/extend function, the interpreter complains it to be a string object instead. Here's the sample source file(text). The text files I will parsing from are huge in size so only adding the interesting text.

```
!
interface Vlan2268
 description SNMA_Lovetch_mgmt
 mtu 1546
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.56 2268 encapsulation mpls
!
interface Vlan2269
 description SNMA_Targoviste_mgmt
 mtu 1546
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.90 2269 encapsulation mpls
!
interface Vlan2272
 mtu 1546
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.72 2272 encapsulation mpls
!
interface Vlan2282
 description SNMA_Ruse_mgmt
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.38 2282 encapsulation mpls
!
interface Vlan2284
 mtu 1546
 no ip address
 xconnect vfi SNMA_Razgrad_mgmt
!
interface Vlan2286
 description mgmt_SNMA_Rs
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.86 2286 encapsulation mpls
!
interface Vlan2292
 description SNMA_Vraca_mgmt
 mtu 1546
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.60 2292 encapsulation mpls
!
```

Comment: Have you noticed that you were using the variable i in both for loops? :)

Comment: Actually, Python knows it's a different variable, but to the human reader it's confusing.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's what I had in mind too..

Comment: Actually, it *is* the same variable. It only works because the inner loop is at the end of the body of the outer loop. If you used `i` in the outer loop after finishing the inner loop, its value would have been the last element of `interfaceslist`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is very simple. Strings are immutable, so you can't `append` to or `extend` them. You have to create a new string using concatenation.

```
>>> print i
interface Vlan2286
 description mgmt_SNMA_Rs
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.86 2286 encapsulation mpls

>>> print i + ' mtu 1546\n'
interface Vlan2286
 description mgmt_SNMA_Rs
 no ip address
 xconnect 22.93.94.86 2286 encapsulation mpls
 mtu 1546
```

Then you have to save the result, either to a variable name or some kind of container. You could just save it to i like so:

```
i = i + ' mtu 1546\n'
```

or like so:

```
i += ' mtu 1546\n'
```

But in this case, a list comprehension might be useful...

```
def add_mtu(i):
    return i if "mtu" in i else i + " mtu 1546\n"

for iface in interfaces:
    interfaceslist = iface.split("!")
    updated_ifaces = [add_mtu(i) for i in interfaceslist]
```

Note that I replaced the first `i` with `iface` for clarity. And also, it appears to me that there's only one `iface` in `interfaces` right now. Perhaps you need that for loop, but if not, it would simplify things to remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot senderle, it looks awesome!! I will try it soon and let you know.. Thanks again..

Comment: senderle - It works great with MTU.. How about concerning  description statement along with MTU. How do I go about integrating that side of the code? Do I have to create a different function for that? Any code will be appreciated.. I have cases where either of the statements "mtu" or "description" could be missing from the text file or both. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: You could just modify the current `add_mtu` function. Instead of returning the result of `i if "mtu" in...`, save it to a variable name and do the same thing with the description.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read the entire file:

```
import re

f = open('/TESTFOLDER/TEST.txt','r')
text = f.read()

text = re.sub(r"(?m)(^interface Vlan\d+.*\n(?! description )", r"\1 description TEST\n", text)
text = re.sub(r"(?m)(^interface Vlan\d+.*\n description .+\n)(?! mtu )", r"\1 mtu 1546\n", text)
```